# making a pdf file in my php database

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have my code in php and I am planning to make a pdf from my database. I try to read and found tcpdf for creating a pdf. i download it and try some of its code.. Is $html really needed when creating pdf? or my code below with echo is okay?  There is an error always whenever i run:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\TopHealth\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 16906

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\TopHealth\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17277

TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file..

```
<?PHP

require_once('tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');


$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM critical");

echo "<center>";
echo "<table class='table1'>
<tr class='tablelist'>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Item Description</th>
<th>Beginning Balance</th>
<th>Reg. Quantity</th>
<th>Quantity Received</th>
<th>Consumed</th>
<th>Stock Level</th>
<th>Critical?</th>
</tr>";
echo "</center>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<tr  class='tablelist'>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CODE'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Item_Description'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Beginning_Balance'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Reg_Quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Quantity_Received'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Consumed'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Stock_Level'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['rate'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


   $pdf->Output('name.pdf', 'I');

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
while (ob_get_level())
        ob_end_clean();
        header("Content-Encoding: None", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you already output some data when echoing it with php.

```
echo "<center>";
```

That won't work because you don't want to have html data before your actual PDF data, which TCPDF generates.

`$html` also hasn't been defined yet, has it?

You might want to create a string, then pass it to `TCPDF`:

```
$html = '<center';
$html .= '<table></table>';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Answer (score -1):

use fpdf..

http://www.fpdf.org/

Read and Experiment